# Feedback on Video Metadata Extraction

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, data-mining, digital-signal-processing

I've developed/patented a metadata extraction methodology, which we've used to build a variety of alternative datasets for funds.

One of the more difficult issues in this field, is getting useful feedback from funds and how the data is actually being used once licensed.

I'd genuinely appreciate feedback on the JSON/metadata we return, the easiest way to review the JSON is via a GUI built from the JSON.

Our key data can be used to minesignals based on combinations of ASR, object detection and concept extraction.

If possible I'd love to hear feedback on usefulness or types of alternative datasets you'd like to see.  Thanks much, feedback is invaluable.

(Keep in mind we have access to mainstream financial audio and video streams going back nearly 10 years/365000 minutes)

Here is a analyzed video for demonstration purposes.

http://www.datascription.com/videogui/